# Use nested perl command to replace part of line

Tags: perl

I have two perl commands and I want to apply one of the commands to replace a capture group in the other command.

Command 1 converts a CamelCase string to snake_case.
It works as expected:

```
echo 'AbcDefGhi' \
  | perl -p -E 's/(?:\b|(?<=([a-z])))([A-Z][a-z]+)/(defined($1) ? "_" : "") . lc($2)/eg'
```

Result:

```
abc_def_ghi
```

Command 2 finds the CamelCase strings that need to be replaced.
It works fine, too (replacing with XXX$1YYY here):

```
echo '  <div id="AbcDefGhi">' \
  | perl -p -E 's#  <div id="([^"]*)">#<div id="XXX$1YYY">#s'
```

Result:

```
  <div id="XXXAbcDefGhiYYY">
```

But how would I combine both commands now? I tried a lot of stuff, but can't get it to work. My best, probably very bad, attempt was to use the e modifier in command 1 and then printf "$1" and pipe that into command 2, but then I think it accessed the wrong $1 from the outside perl command.

Ideally I want to have it work something like this:

```
echo '  <div id="AbcDefGhi">' | perl -p -E 's#  <div id="([^"]*)">#MAGIC#s'
```

Result:

```
  <div id="abc_def_ghi">
```

Solutions with other tools are welcome too, but I would really like to improve to perl knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically one one-liner is to locate the correct string, and the other to change that string. Well, you're already using the `/e` modifier, so why not just insert the substitution in there?

```
perl -p -E 's#  <div id="([^"]*)">#
    qq(<div id=") . 
    $1 =~ s/(?:\b|(?<=([a-z])))([A-Z][a-z]+)/(defined($1) ? "_" : "") . lc($2)/egr .
    qq(">)#sex'
```

Basically we did this:

```
perl -pE' s# .... # s/...// # '
```

It's a bit of a mouthful to read, so I split it up using the `/x` modifier, but you can just remove that and put it on a single line.

Note that I added the `/r` modifier, because we don't want to change `$1` (we can't, it's read-only), we just want the value after substitution. And that is what `/r` does, perform the substitution and return the string, but leave original string unchanged.

Luckily you had also already change delimiters on `s///` so we don't even need to do that.

This is what the line would look like, for copy/paste purposes:

```
perl -p -E 's#  <div id="([^"]*)">#qq(<div id=") . $1 =~ s/(?:\b|(?<=([a-z])))([A-Z][a-z]+)/(defined($1) ? "_" : "") . lc($2)/egr . qq(">)#se'
```

I'm sure the better way is to write a simpler command, but this is the quick way to merge your commands.